# Showing the ajax-data in bootstrap

Tags: ajax, laravel, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I have this code for viewing all the gathered data from database using ajax which is working but only when I use input tags read-only. Is there any way to show data like in Table (which i really want).

The view.blade

```
<div id="viewInfo" class="modal fade" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header" style="color: green;">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id=""><strong>Full Details</strong></h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true" style="color: white;" >&times;</span>
                        </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body" style="font-size: 10px;" >
                    <form>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="staticEmail" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Name</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="text" readonly class="form-control-plaintext" id="name2">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="staticEmail" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Email/Username</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="text" readonly class="form-control-plaintext" id="email2">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="staticEmail" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Address</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="text" readonly class="form-control-plaintext" id="address2">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="staticEmail" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Phone Number</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="text" readonly class="form-control-plaintext" id="phone_number2">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="staticEmail" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Household Type</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="text" readonly class="form-control-plaintext" id="type2">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="staticEmail" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Active Status </label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="text" readonly class="form-control-plaintext" id="active_status2">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="staticEmail" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Password </label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="text" readonly class="form-control-plaintext" id="password2">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="staticEmail" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Transactions </label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="text" readonly class="form-control-plaintext" id="">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>


                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The Script

```
   $('.view_data').click(function(){
        event.preventDefault();
        var household_id = $(this).attr("id");
        $.ajax({
            url:"{{ route('householdInfo') }}",
            method:"get",
            data:{household_id:household_id},
            dataType:"json",
            success:function(data){
                $('#name2').val(data.firstname);
                $('#address2').val(data.address);
                $('#phone_number2').val(data.phone_number);
                $('#type2').val(data.type);
                $('#email2').val(data.email);
                $('#active_status2').val(data.active_status);
                $('#password2').val(data.password);
                $('#viewInfo2').appendTo('body').modal('show');
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    });
```

I'd like to do it not using input tags in readonly. A very much thank you for anyone who could help me about this.

Answer (score 0):

Make change to your blade file

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Sr no</th>
            <th>Country</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

You just need to change the success function of the ajax

```
success: function(data) {
    $.each(data.results, function(index,val){
        $("tbody").append("<tr><td>"index+"</td><td>"+val.country+"</td></tr>");
    });
},
```